# How to show a message when collection view is empty

Tags: ios, swift

I`m trying to show a message only when my collection view is empty. Well, I try set return 1 when my if is true but when I have this, it only show one item in my collection view (even if I had more). And when I return this (code bellow) it shows all the items I have in my collection view but when I try to delete it, the last one is not "deletable", I mean, the last one stays there. How can I show this message only if I have no items in my collection view?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if self.movies.count > 0 {

        self.favCollectionView.backgroundView = nil

        return self.movies.count
    }
    else {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0,
                          y: 0,
                          width: self.favCollectionView.bounds.size.width,
                          height: self.favCollectionView.bounds.size.height)
        let noDataLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: rect)
        noDataLabel.text = "No favorite movies yet."
        noDataLabel.textAlignment = .center
        noDataLabel.textColor = UIColor.gray
        noDataLabel.sizeToFit()

        self.favCollectionView.backgroundView = noDataLabel

        return 0
    }
}
```

---

### Update

I did it like this:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 { return self.movies.count}
    else if section == 1 {
        if self.movies.count < 1 { return 1 }
        else { return 0  }
    }
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = favCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FavCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! FavoritesCollectionViewCell

    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        let movie = movies[indexPath.row]

        let imgStg: String = movie.posterURL!
        let imgURL: URL? = URL(string: imgStg)
        let imgSrc = ImageResource(downloadURL: imgURL!, cacheKey: imgStg)

        cell.favTitleLabel.text = movie.title

        cell.favPosterImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.favPosterImageView.frame.size.width/2
        cell.favPosterImageView.clipsToBounds = true

        //image cache with KingFisher
        cell.favPosterImageView.kf.setImage(with: imgSrc)

        return cell

    }

    else {

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.favCollectionView.frame.width, height: self.favCollectionView.frame.height)
        let noDataLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: rect)
        noDataLabel.text = "No favorite movies yet."
        noDataLabel.textAlignment = .center
        noDataLabel.textColor = UIColor.gray
        noDataLabel.sizeToFit()

        let cell = UICollectionViewCell()
        cell.contentView.addSubview(noDataLabel)

        return cell

    }

}
```

For @Lamar's solution, but the app crashed with error: 
[image]

Answer (score 60):

I make use of the `backgroundView` in an extension as such:

```
extension UICollectionView {

    func setEmptyMessage(_ message: String) {
        let messageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.size.width, height: self.bounds.size.height))
        messageLabel.text = message
        messageLabel.textColor = .black
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        messageLabel.textAlignment = .center;
        messageLabel.font = UIFont(name: "TrebuchetMS", size: 15)
        messageLabel.sizeToFit()

        self.backgroundView = messageLabel;
    }

    func restore() {
        self.backgroundView = nil
    }
}
```

and I use it as such:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if (self.movies.count == 0) {
        self.collectionView.setEmptyMessage("Nothing to show :(")
    } else {
        self.collectionView.restore()
    }

    return self.movies.count
}
```

Comment: This is great thank you. Any strategies to use when loading data and count is always at 0?

Comment: I'd disagree with putting this kind of side effect laden code in what is essentially an accessor (numberOfItemsInSection) What you are doing is taking what should be a very low overhead call and creating a UILabel every time it gets called.

Comment: backgroundView is boken https://blog.spacemanlabs.com/2013/11/uicollectionviews-backgroundview-property-is-horribly-broken/

Answer (score 6):

Maybe little bit late but here is little more **constraint based** solution. Still may help some one.

First create some empty state message (You can also create own, more complex view with image or something).

```
    lazy var emptyStateMessage: UILabel = {
        let messageLabel = UILabel()
        messageLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        messageLabel.textColor = .darkGray
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        messageLabel.textAlignment = .center;
        messageLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        messageLabel.sizeToFit()
        return messageLabel
    }()
```

Then add two methods and call them whenever you like.

```
    func showEmptyState() {
        collectionView.addSubview(emptyStateMessage)
        emptyStateMessage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.centerXAnchor).activate()
        emptyStateMessage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.centerYAnchor).activate()
    }

    func hideEmptyState() {
        emptyStateMessage.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `backgroundView` of your Collection View to display the no results message.

Answer (score 0):

I would say have **two sections** in your collectionView, where one is for the actual data to be displayed, then the other one when you don't have any data.

> Assuming we are populating data in section 0.

in `numberOfRowsInSection` you'd have something like:

```
     if section == 0 { return movies.count}
     else if section == 1 {
          if movies.count < 1 { return 1 }
          else { return 0  }
     }
        return 0
```

in your `cellForItemAt` you'd do something like that:

```
 if indexPath.section == 0 {
      // let cell = ...
      // show your data into your cell 
        return cell  
     }else {
          // here you handle the case where there is no data, but the big thing is we are not dequeuing  
          let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.favCollectionView.frame.width, height: self.favCollectionView.frame.height)
        let noDataLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: rect)
        noDataLabel.text = "No favorite movies yet."
        noDataLabel.textAlignment = .center
        noDataLabel.textColor = UIColor.gray
        noDataLabel.sizeToFit()

        let cell = UICollectionViewCell()
        cell.contentView.addSubview(noDataLabel)

       return cell
      }
```

Comment: I try this but the app crashs when I click to show my collection view

Comment: I updated the question with a image showing the error

Comment: what is the error, I cant see the issue in the screenshot, and did you return 2 from `numberOfSections`

Comment: I'm sorry, but your example is for a table view right? on my collection view I'm only using two functions "numberOfItemsInSection" (so I put your first example here) and a "cellForItemAt" (where I put the second one). But the app is crashing and I don`t know the error. It only show me this (the image).

Comment: You have to show me what you have in the debugger ... The image you gave is not complete

Comment: oh, sorry about that. Where can I found this?

Comment: Ok, I did change. Please take another look the the update of my question. I put my code and the fatal error on my console.

Comment: You didn't do what I have... at cellForItemAt

Comment: Sorry about that. It was a mess and I decided to do it from scratch and forgot that part. Now I guess is all set like you said, but the app still crashing. Is this image telling something about this crash?

Comment: Move that line inside the If block 'let cell = favCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FavCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! FavoritesCollectionViewCell'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143339/discussion-between-lamar-and-u23r).

Comment: It seems your collectionViewCell named "FavCollectionCell" said in the error message console that you didn't set the same name in the Storyboard when you click on your custom cell in the "Attribute Inspector" you can see in "Collection Reusable View" an "Identifier" section then here you just put the same name as "FavCollectionCell" and keep this line in your code: let cell = favCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FavCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! FavoritesCollectionViewCell. Hope it helps, and if your issue is already fixed, it will be appreciate if you can share it

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use:

> `open var backgroundView: UIView?`
>
> // will be automatically resized to track the size of the collection view and placed behind all cells and supplementary views.`

You can show it whenever collection is empty. Example:

```
var collectionView: UICollectionView!
var collectionData: [Any] {
    didSet {
        collectionView.backgroundView?.alpha = collectionData.count > 0 ? 1.0 : 0.0
    }
}
```